# How to know if an adress is valid within a page

Tags: virtual-memory, mmu

Vistual and physical memory are divided into pages. To check if a page is valid there is a valid bit in the page table entry. But within a page how can the MMU know if an adress is valid? For example, a page that belongs to a part of the heap. not all the adresses of that page are valid, so how can the MMU check the addr to see if its valid?

Answer (score 0):

A page is the smallest unit of memory that the MMU stores information about; that's basically the definition of 'page'.  Therefore, all addresses within a page are equally valid or not.  If part of a page is something you don't intend to be accessible (it's outside of any allocated object, perhaps), that's not something the MMU can detect.

Answer (score 0):

Logical memory is divided into PAGES. Physical memory is divided into PAGE FRAMES. The page table:

1. Identifies which logical pages are part of the process address space
2. The protection for the page
3. The mapping to a physical page from (or no mapping in the case of virtual memory that is paged out).

The validity of an memory access depends upon the type of access, current processor mode, and the state of the page tables.

Logically, when a memory access takes place the processor:

1. Breaks the address into a logical page and an offset into the logical page (that depends upon the page size).
2. Looks up the page table entry for the logical page. It is possible that no page table entry exists. In linear page tables, the size of the table may be restricted. In multi-level page tables, there may not be a nested table for the page. If there is corresponding entry => Access Violation.
3. Checks to see if the page table entry indicates a valid page. This is usually done with a valid bit but there are other ways of doing it. If the page is invalid => Access violation.
4. Checks to see if the type of access (read/write/execute) is permitted for the page in the current processor mode. If not => Access violation
5. Checks to see if the logical page maps to a physical page frame (this is often done as part of step #3). If not => Page Fault

A "heap" is just memory. A process can have multiple heaps simultaneously. A heap manager maps pages into the logical address space then manages those pages. A heap does not even need to reside in contiguous memory.

While high level memory diagrams usually show "a heap" these are gross simplifications of what goes on.